How do I Troubleshoot a Microsoft.Indentity.Client Access Token when MailKit returns Authentication Failed?
I am building an email automation application to login to a mailbox, extract text and sort the emails etc.  I am trying to use the MailKit library but running into some issues logging into the inbox which is a Microsoft 365 tenant.
I have worked through the registration of the app within Microsoft Infra that is listed in the documentation for Microsoft.Indentity.Client
I am using the following code from MailKit's GitHub.
 var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("xxxx")
 .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{"xxxxx"}/v2.0")
 .WithClientSecret("xxxx")
 .Build();

 var scopes = new string[] {

     "https://ps.outlook.com/.default"

 };


 var authToken = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
 var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(username, authToken.AccessToken);

 using (var client = new ImapClient())
 {
     await client.ConnectAsync("outlook.office365.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
     await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);
     await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
 }

I am now getting back an Access Token with the assigned scope from this line
var authToken = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
But when it is processed by MailKit, this object shows that it is not authenticated
var oauth2
and this line throws an Authentication Failed Error.
await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);
I have used the code sample that pops up a Microsoft login to authenticate and everything works fine, so the mailbox setup seems to be ok with imap, but I cannot figure out what could be wrong.
Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I can breakdown the AuthToken object to look for issues, or to get more information from the authentication failure?
here is the code that does work, albeit with a popup microsoft authenticator.
            var options = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "xxxxx",
                TenantId = "xxxxx",            
                RedirectUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient"

            };

            var publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .CreateWithApplicationOptions(options)
                .Build();

            var scopes = new string[] {
                "email",
                "offline_access",
                "https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All", // Only needed for IMAP

            };

            var authToken = await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
            var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(authToken.Account.Username, authToken.AccessToken);

            using (var client = new ImapClient())
            {
                await client.ConnectAsync("outlook.office365.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
                await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);
                await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
            }

This however is not an option since this program will basically run as a scheduled task on a server somewhere.
Hope I have explained it well enough.
Thanks,
